# XMLELEMENT SQL Function name allows colon or not

Tags: sql, xml, db2

I am using IBMi 7.3: DB2 for i SQL reference. The documentation of XMLELEMENT function there is something like this:

```
XMLELEMENT ( NAME element-name ...
```

element-name is defined as:

> **NAME element-name**
>   Specifies the name of an XML element. The name is an SQL identifier that
>   must be in the form of an XML qualified name, or QName. See the W3C XML
>   namespace specifications for more details on valid names. If the name is
>   qualified, the namespace prefix must be declared within the scope

The examples which I have found till now(in DB2 i reference: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscaxmlelem.htm And DB2 LUW reference https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0022188.html) are specifying element-name always in quotes.

Example:

```
SELECT E.EMPNO, E.FIRSTNME, E.LASTNAME,
XMLELEMENT(NAME "foo:Emp",
XMLNAMESPACES(’http://www.foo.com’ AS "foo"),
XMLATTRIBUTES(E.EMPNO AS "serial"),
E.FIRSTNME, E.LASTNAME
OPTION EMPTY ON NULL) AS "Result"
FROM SESSION.CANDIDATES E
```

It is not mentioned clearly that it could be without quotes or not. Also examples showing use of colon inside names. But when I tried it on IBM i (green screen), It was showing message of **Invalid SQL Name**. Is it possible to use colons without quote in names.

Comment: Your link is to Db2 for LUW docs, not Db2 for IBM i..

Comment: Yes, link is of Db2 LUW, I have found example of XMLELEMENT there, thats why i have mentioned it.

Comment: My answer has a link to the Db2 i docs from which I pulled my example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML element names are case sensitive...

```
XMLELEMENT(NAME cef, e.firstname)
```

results in `<CEF>Charles</CEF>`

```
XMLELEMENT(NAME "cef", e.firstname)
```

results in `<cef>Charles</cef>`

Which are not the same.

The colon in `:CITY` only matters for SQL embedded in RPGLE or another language.

I don't believe you could ever have a colon in the element name, unless you're using a namespace, in that case you need the quotes.

from the [docs](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzscaxmlelem.htm)

```
SELECT E.EMPNO, E.FIRSTNME, E.LASTNAME,
      XMLELEMENT(NAME "foo:Emp"
                 , XMLNAMESPACES(’http://www.foo.com’ AS "foo")
                 , XMLATTRIBUTES(E.EMPNO AS "serial")
                 , E.FIRSTNME, E.LASTNAME
                 OPTION NULL ON NULL) AS "Result"
 FROM SESSION.CANDIDATES E
```

Comment: Thanks @Charles for your answer.

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to use name without quote. This I have verified by creating an example.

```
SELECT XMLSERIALIZE(                       
XMLCONCAT(                                 
XMLELEMENT(NAME cef, e.firstname),         
XMLELEMENT(NAME "last", e.lastname)        
) AS VARCHAR(100) ) AS "result" 
FROM ABHTEST.EMPLOYEE E
```

This is resulting into:

```
 <CEF>Abhishek </CEF><last>Tiwari </last>
```

When putting cef in quotes then the result is as :

```
<cef>Abhishek </cef><last>Tiwari </last>
```

But the issue is that colon is allowed in name either without quotes or with quotes.